# hablar::dte() Issue in converting a datetime of class POSIXct to a date

Tags: r, date, posixct

In R 4.2.3, I found that applying dte() to date times of a class "POSIXct" makes the day one less. The following issue is copied from   https://github.com/davidsjoberg/hablar/issues/17; please see the link for more information.

> Thank you for allowing a package that quickly allows me to change
> classes of variables. I found that applying `dte()` to date times of a
> class  "POSIXct" makes the day be one less.  Please see the example
> below.
>
> ````
> library(magrittr)
>
> A <- read_excel(   readxl_example("deaths.xlsx"),   range =
> "arts!A5:F15",   .name_repair = "universal" )
> #> New names:
> #> • `Has kids` -> `Has.kids`
> #> • `Date of birth` -> `Date.of.birth`
> #> • `Date of death` -> `Date.of.death` class(A$Date.of.birth)
> #> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" A
> #> # A tibble: 10 × 6
> #>    Name            Profe…¹   Age Has.k…² Date.of.birth       Date.of.death      
> #>    <chr>           <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
> #>  1 David Bowie     musici…    69 TRUE    1947-01-08 00:00:00 2016-01-10 00:00:00
> #>  2 Carrie Fisher   actor      60 TRUE    1956-10-21 00:00:00 2016-12-27 00:00:00
> #>  3 Chuck Berry     musici…    90 TRUE    1926-10-18 00:00:00 2017-03-18 00:00:00
> #>  4 Bill Paxton     actor      61 TRUE    1955-05-17 00:00:00 2017-02-25 00:00:00
> #>  5 Prince          musici…    57 TRUE    1958-06-07 00:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00
> #>  6 Alan Rickman    actor      69 FALSE   1946-02-21 00:00:00 2016-01-14 00:00:00
> #>  7 Florence Hende… actor      82 TRUE    1934-02-14 00:00:00 2016-11-24 00:00:00
> #>  8 Harper Lee      author     89 FALSE   1926-04-28 00:00:00 2016-02-19 00:00:00
> #>  9 Zsa Zsa Gábor   actor      99 TRUE    1917-02-06 00:00:00 2016-12-18 00:00:00
> #> 10 George Michael  musici…    53 FALSE   1963-06-25 00:00:00 2016-12-25 00:00:00
> #> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​Profession, ²​Has.kids A %>% hablar::convert(dte(starts_with("Date")))
> #> # A tibble: 10 × 6
> #>    Name               Profession   Age Has.kids Date.of.birth Date.of.death
> #>    <chr>              <chr>      <dbl> <lgl>    <date>        <date>       
> #>  1 David Bowie        musician      69 TRUE     1947-01-07    2016-01-09   
> #>  2 Carrie Fisher      actor         60 TRUE     1956-10-20    2016-12-26   
> #>  3 Chuck Berry        musician      90 TRUE     1926-10-17    2017-03-17   
> #>  4 Bill Paxton        actor         61 TRUE     1955-05-16    2017-02-24   
> #>  5 Prince             musician      57 TRUE     1958-06-06    2016-04-20   
> #>  6 Alan Rickman       actor         69 FALSE    1946-02-20    2016-01-13   
> #>  7 Florence Henderson actor         82 TRUE     1934-02-13    2016-11-23   
> #>  8 Harper Lee         author        89 FALSE    1926-04-27    2016-02-18   
> #>  9 Zsa Zsa Gábor      actor         99 TRUE     1917-02-05    2016-12-17   
> #> 10 George Michael     musician      53 FALSE    1963-06-24    2016-12-24 Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex
> v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) ```
>
> For example, instead of the date of birth for Bowie being
> `1947-01-08", the day becomes "1947-01-07".  The same is true for all
> dates of these musicians. 
>
> I know that package **readxl** read the data right as this is the
> excel sheet that the data came from. The dates match identically
> between the excel and the resulting R tibble.  <img width="502"
> alt="Annotation 2023-03-27 093609"
> src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17706062/227954203-ae72f540-730a-4f1d-b472-57cdce131c16.png">
>
> The packages and versions used: ``` R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10
> x64 (build 19045), RStudio 2023.3.0.386
>
> Locale:   LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
> LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8      LC_MONETARY=English_United
> States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                            
> LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
>
> Package version:   base64enc_0.1.3   bslib_0.4.2       cachem_1.0.7   
> callr_3.7.3       cellranger_1.1.0    cli_3.6.0         clipr_0.8.0   
> compiler_4.2.3    cpp11_0.4.3       crayon_1.5.2        digest_0.6.31 
> dplyr_1.1.0       ellipsis_0.3.2    evaluate_0.20     fansi_1.0.4     
> fastmap_1.1.1     fs_1.6.1          generics_0.1.3    glue_1.6.2      
> graphics_4.2.3      grDevices_4.2.3   hablar_0.3.2      highr_0.10    
> hms_1.1.2         htmltools_0.5.4     jquerylib_0.1.4   jsonlite_1.8.4
> knitr_1.42        lifecycle_1.0.3   lubridate_1.9.2     magrittr_2.0.3
> memoise_2.0.1     methods_4.2.3     mime_0.12         pillar_1.8.1    
> pkgconfig_2.0.3   prettyunits_1.1.1 processx_3.8.0    progress_1.2.2  
> ps_1.7.3            purrr_1.0.1       R6_2.5.1          rappdirs_0.3.3
> readxl_1.4.2      rematch_1.0.1       reprex_2.0.2      rlang_1.1.0   
> rmarkdown_2.20    rstudioapi_0.14   sass_0.4.5          stats_4.2.3   
> stringi_1.7.12    stringr_1.5.0     tibble_3.2.1      tidyselect_1.2.0
> timechange_0.2.0  tinytex_0.44      tools_4.2.3       utf8_1.2.3      
> utils_4.2.3         vctrs_0.6.0       withr_2.5.0       xfun_0.37     
> yaml_2.3.7       ```
> ````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/davidsjoberg/hablar/issues/17 for a potential answer. The contents are shown below in case the linked page becomes invalidated:

> For some reason, `strftime` removes a day for dates that have times at
> midnight. According to the documentation, changes have been made in R
> versions 4.2.0 and following:
>
> > strftime is a wrapper for format.POSIXlt, and it and format.POSIXct first convert to class "POSIXlt" by calling
> > [as.POSIXlt](http://127.0.0.1:30443/help/library/base/help/as.POSIXlt)
> > (so they also work for class
> > "[Date](http://127.0.0.1:30443/help/library/base/help/Date)"). Note
> > that only that conversion depends on the time zone. Since R version
> > 4.2.0, that as.POSIXlt() conversion now treats the non-finite numeric -Inf, Inf, NA and NaN differently (where previously all were treated as NA) and also the format() method for POSIXlt now treats these
> > different non-finite times and dates analogously to type
> > [double](http://127.0.0.1:30443/help/library/base/help/double).
>
> Using `as.Date()` for variables belonging to the POSIXct class solves
> the problem, so the checking of the POSIXct class is not needed. I
> don't have the writing permissions to pull a request.
>
> ````
>     if (any(class(.x) == "Date")) {
>       return(.x)
>     }
>     if (is.logical(.x)) {
>       stop("Logical vectors can't be converted to date.")
>     }
>     if (is.factor(.x)) {
>       .x <- as.character(.x)
>     }
>     # if (any(class(.x) == "POSIXct")) {
>     #   .x <- strftime(.x)
>     # }
>     if (TRUE) {
>       return(as.Date(.x, ...))
>     }   } ```
>
> Note to other users: The function `as_reliable_dte()` is an internal
> function that is called by `dte()`.  ```{r} dte <- function (...,
> .args = list()) {   list(vars = dplyr::quos(...), fun =
> ~as_reliable_dte(., !!!.args)) }
>
>
> A <- read_excel(   readxl_example("deaths.xlsx"),   range =
> "arts!A5:F15",   .name_repair = "universal" )  A %>%
> hablar::convert(dte(starts_with("Date"))) ``` ```
> # A tibble: 10 × 6    Name               Profession   Age Has.kids Date.of.birth Date.of.death    <chr>              <chr>      <dbl>
> <lgl>    <date>        <date>         1 David Bowie        musician   
> 69 TRUE     1947-01-08    2016-01-10     2 Carrie Fisher      actor   
> 60 TRUE     1956-10-21    2016-12-27     3 Chuck Berry        musician
> 90 TRUE     1926-10-18    2017-03-18     4 Bill Paxton        actor   
> 61 TRUE     1955-05-17    2017-02-25     5 Prince             musician
> 57 TRUE     1958-06-07    2016-04-21     6 Alan Rickman       actor   
> 69 FALSE    1946-02-21    2016-01-14     7 Florence Henderson actor   
> 82 TRUE     1934-02-14    2016-11-24     8 Harper Lee         author  
> 89 FALSE    1926-04-28    2016-02-19     9 Zsa Zsa Gábor      actor   
> 99 TRUE     1917-02-06    2016-12-18    10 George Michael     musician
> 53 FALSE    1963-06-25    2016-12-25    ```
> ````